# Possible wrongly closed question: "No space left on device" when installing packages, yet I have space left

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I would like to point out that this question ["No space left on device" when installing packages, yet I have space left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485743/) should not be a duplicate of this other [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

`apt-get` fails due to `No space left on device` so I don't think that is related to unmet dependencies.

I apologize, I tried to use the chat, but without success, and I'm not sure that flag is the right way to point out possible wrong closed question, isn't it?

Comment: sorry I got busy and then forgot to reply to your message. Yes, a flag would be appropriate, although posting here is ok too.

Comment: no problem, it seemed rude fit into the chat while people discuss, I thought it was wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post has been reopened (see the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/485743/revisions)) - I suppose that solves this issue.

Comment: yes, I had seen, thanks to all